# How do I get MathJax (CDN) to use Latin-Modern instead of STIX?

Tags: fonts, mathjax

I am able to get the STIX font mathematical symbols to show by putting

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"></script>
```

in the head of app/views/application.html.erb.

However, I want it to use the Latin-Modern font. In my application.js file, I added

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {
    preferredFont: "Latin-Modern"
    }
});
```

But, Latin-Modern doesn't render on the page.

Note: I am able to render mathematical symbols and equations with MacTex and I have installed 'latinmodern-math.otf' from http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `preferredFont` tells MathJax which of the local font (from the `availableFonts` list) to used, if it is available.  It is unlikely that your users will have the MathJax versions of the Latin-Modern fonts installed locally.  Instead, if you want to force Latin-Modern, you will need to prevent the use of local fonts, and tell MathJax to use the Latin-Modern web font.  Use

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {
    availableFonts: [],
    preferredFont: null,
    webFont: "Latin-Modern"
  }
});
```

There is also a newer (and not well documented) method of setting all three at once using the `fonts` property.  This gives an array of fonts to look for locally, with the first one being preferred, and the first used as the web font if none is found locally.  So

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {
    fonts: ["Latin-Modern"]
  }
});
```

should also do it.

Comment: I love Stackoverflow!